# Regex - Select "<?" but not "<?php"

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use regex to select instances where something like `<?` (a php construct is used but not `<?php`. I've tried several iterations on [regextester](http://www.regextester.com/) but have failed. Here's the latest `<\?(?!<\?php)`

Basically this is what I want. it covers all the variations in my document

```
<?php foo ?> //should not match
<? bar ?> //should match '<?'
<?=foobar ?> //should match '<?='
<?xml barbar ?> //should not match
```

I'm new to regex so any help would be appreciated

**Edit**: With the problems with the answers posted I'm adding one more condition to match

```
<?php foo ?> //should not match
<? bar ?> //should match '<?'
<?bar ?> //should match '<?' there could be any character after ?
<?=foobar ?> //should match '<?='
<?xml barbar ?> //should not match
```

To summarize, I'm only trying to match `<?` or `<?=` not the complete line they occur in.

**Edit 2**: Basically the logic of the expression should be: match `<?` or `<?=` but not if followed by `php' or 'xml'

Comment: Use this:- (<\?(?=\s))|(<\?=)

Comment: I'd suggest [`<\?[^\w\s]*+(?!(?:php|xml)\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/tL3oK9/1) but not sure if there are any other exceptions. However, I think I found a more generic approach, please see my answer.

Comment: please be as precise as you want, I've added all possibilities in my document

Comment: For the record, `<?=foobar ?>` and `<?bar ?>` would throw syntax errors and would fail to execute if run by PHP, as a valid opening tag must be followed by some sort of whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc). So if your goal to find **valid** php code, those two would actually **not** be valid.

Comment: Actually I received some code and I need to find these invalid tags so I could replace them with valid ones. That's why I wanna skip `<?php`, cauz it's valid already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it.

```
<\?=?(?!php)(?!xml)
```

This will match `<?` with an optional `=` not followed by the string 'php' and 'xml'

Comment: You don't need 2 negative loookahead assertions. Check my answer it can done as `(?!php|xml)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
<\?=?(?!php|xml)
```

`(?!php|xml)` will fail the match if there is `php` or `xml` text after `<?` ir `,?=`, thus failing `<?php` and `<?xml`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQ9wP7/3)

Comment: but it should match `<?=`

Comment: No you're selecting the whole line with that code. I only needed the `<?` and `<?=`. Put `<\?=?(?!php)(?!xml)` in your demo and see the difference.

Comment: [It works in demo also](https://regex101.com/r/mQ9wP7/3) It had your comments after each input string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<\?[^\w\s]+|<\?\B
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uC6aB9/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `<\?[^\w\s]+` - a literal `<?` sequence followed with 1+ characters other than a word and whitespace
- `|` - or
- `<\?\B` - `<?` literal character sequence followed with a non-word boundary (meaning there should be a non-word character right after `?`).

Answer (score 0):

Use below regex:-

```
(<\?(?=\s).*)|(<\?=.*)
```

It will match both record

```
<? bar ?> 
<?=foobar ?>
```

If you write only

```
(<\?(?=\s))|(<\?=)
```

the it will match `<?` and `<?=` only